# How to open emoji keyboard like whatsapp in ionic 1

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on ionic app and need emoji with text, I want somthing like whatsapp, In whatsapp when they click on emoji button , emoji keyboard appear.
Its default keyboard of android and I am ok with it.

I dont want to use any plugin like https://github.com/danielehrhardt/ionic3-emoji-picker because they provide own set of images/css . I want to use default emoji of android.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic uses HTML components in a webview to render your app.
With HTML components (`<input>`) it is currently **not possible** to suggest the emoji keyboard.

A suggestion exists for numbers e.g. `<input type="number">` and there is an [open issue](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/495) on the W3 issue tracker to add emoji support.

Comment: Its trigger default android emoji keyboard

Comment: because whatsapp is a native app.
To achieve this with ionic, you need a plugin with a native implementation

Comment: I can use plugin but they have own set of emoji , I want any how we can use default one